# Why is the answer is runtime exception will occur?

Tags: c#

[image]

I just started learning the C# language. I came across this question and I could not figure out why is the answer is runtime exception will occur. Thank you in advance.

I tried to understand the code and from my understanding by using List can contain elements of the specified type. Based on the question, the type of elements are string. The elements are added by using the `AddRange` function. I have read that elements can be added this way.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-8.0

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code (and question) directly, not as an image. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: That questions with code example are easily to test by using/executing it yourself. You would have known then what part is the problem what method is the problem and then simply reading the documentation of that. With just asking here the learning experience for you is close to nothing. Try things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SingleOrDefault()` will throw an `InvalidOperationException` when there are more than one value in the source. See the [documentation of `SingleOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-singleordefault-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))):

> #### Exceptions
>
> `InvalidOperationException`
> The input sequence contains more than one element.

Your list `names` has three strings in it, but the `SingleOrDefault()` method expects only one or zero element. That's why you get an exception. It's to ensure (and fail fast) that the source list contains at most one element.